# snakemake expansion no input files

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I have some different configurations and I need to get the combination of them all to run a python script

```py
versions = ['lg', 'sm']
start_time = ['0', '1']
end_time = ['2']
```

What I want is snakemake to do this for me:

```
python my_script.py -v lg -s 0 -e 2 > lg_0_2.out
python my_script.py -v lg -s 1 -e 2 > lg_1_2.out
python my_script.py -v sm -s 0 -e 2 > sm_0_2.out
python my_script.py -v sm -s 1 -e 2 > sm_1_2.out
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in snakemake. Any ideas?

Comment: @merv I see. Good to know. Re-opened then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snakemake has [an `expand()` method](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) that is shorthand for expanding by an outer product, which is the operation you are describing. Typically, this would be accomplished by generating the output file strings as the `input` in the first rule (default rule), and then providing a rule (`myrule` below) that parses such strings to generate the command you would use to generate the outputs. In code, it would go something like

**Snakefile**

```python
versions = ['lg', 'sm']
start_time = ['0', '1']
end_time = ['2']

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{version}_{start}_{end}.out", 
               version=versions, start=start_time, end=end_time)

rule myrule:
    output: "{version,[^_]+}_{start,[0-9]+}_{end,[0-9]+}.out"
    shell:
    """
    python my_script.py -v {wildcards.version} -s {wildcards.start} -e {wildcards.end} > {output}
    """
```

Running `snakemake` in the directory where this `Snakefile` resides would then generate the desired files.

Comment: This works, but in my version I need to have the part in `rule all` as the `input`, and I have my shell command as a simple string. One question I have, though, is why does it need to be in two separate rules? Why can't I just put what's in the `all` rule as the `output` of the `my_rule`? Seems redundant to have both, but when I tried that, snakemake doesn't recognize the parts of the `wildcards` object.

Comment: @jsad sorry about that, I was doing it from memory and forgot the `input:`. Snakemake is sometimes described as a *pull*-based mechanism. It either gets a list of desired outputs from the commandline (you request `snakemake {lg,sm}_{0,1}_2.out`) or from the `input` of the first rule (in which case one just runs `snakemake`). Outputs of rules are then used to match (and parse) the received file strings. In a standard pipeline, you will typically have many rules and only need to list the final outputs that are not dependencies of anything else.

Comment: Thanks, @merv, for that explanation and the helpful answer!